# Django Import Export Inline

Tags: django

I got stuck when using it in inline model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=False)
    courier = models.ForeignKey(Courier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    shipping_charges = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=False)
    payment = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Payment, default='Bank Transfer', null=True, blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=Status, default='Pending', null=True, blank=False)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=False)
    date_modified = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'by ' + str(self.customer)

class Item(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=25, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title
```

I used compactinline with jet admin, when i trying to export data for ITEM got blank data, i want export product too in each order detail. This my export class

```
class OrderExport(resources.ModelResource):
    date_added = Field(attribute='date_added', column_name='Date')
    customer = Field(attribute='customer', column_name='Customer')
    product = fields.Field(attribute='product', column_name='Product', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Item, 'product'))
    courier = Field(attribute='courier', column_name='Courier')
    shipping_charges = Field(attribute='shipping_charges', column_name='Shipping Charges')
    payment = Field(attribute='payment', column_name='Payment')
    status = Field(attribute='status', column_name='Status')

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('date_added', 'customer', 'product', 'courier', 'shipping_charges', 'payment', 'status')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class OrderExport(resources.ModelResource):
    order__date_added = Field(attribute='date_added', column_name='Date')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('order__date_added',-----)
```

try this way

Comment: the problem is not in date but in product. i want in report order have product detail in each order report. Product from ITEM model (inline)

Comment: admin import export not support for inline model or subclass model ?

Comment: YES! it's Correct!!! for subclass model or inline model you need to create root or proxy it first